# How to read boot errors from jboss cli?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

When using hot-deploy via jboss-cli (`deploy --file on_controller.war`) and there is a problem with deploying it, there is some output describing the problem, for example (not actually that pretty printed. ^^):

```
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./THE_WAR" =>
            "< some description containing exceptions etc >"
    }
}
```

When not using hot-deploy, for example when using `<fs-archive />` in `standlone.xml`;
how do I read this errors using jboss-cli?

I know there is the `deployment-info` command, but that only tells *whether* a deployment failed, *but not why*.
I also tried `/deployment=*:query()`, but it also just contains only whether the deployment failed.

Additionally `:read-attribute(server-state)` will return `"running"` even when were error during boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `/core-service=management:read-boot-errors`:

```
[standalone@jboss:9990 /] /core-service=management:read-boot-errors
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => []
}
```

Because that output can be a little bit hard to parse [when using automation](https://gist.github.com/ciis0/7151f1e43e9d55a6953378ceb91e02ad), you can also use JBoss' [HTTP Management API](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#The_HTTP_management_API), which will give you JSON:

```sh
$ curl --digest --location --dump-header - http://$JBOSS_HOST:9990/management/ \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data - --user admin <<EOT
{
    "address": {
        "core-service": "management"
    },
    "operation": "read-boot-errors",
    "json.pretty": 1
}
EOT

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="ManagementRealm", nonce="--%<--", opaque="00000000000000000000000000000000", algorithm=MD5, qop=auth
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 77
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 10:29:33 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 48
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 10:29:33 GMT

{
    "outcome" : "success",
    "result" : []
}
```

(`<<EOT ... EOT` is a [heredoc](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), the rest of the command is [from the documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#lets-read-some-resource))